# Just so you know

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a good way to tell someone that I want to inform them of something, but I don't actually need them to do anything for me. Something like "Just so you know, the printer is broken." As in, I'm not personally affected, but I thought the person in charge would want to be told. If I just say that it's broken, it sounds like a request to fix it so I can use it. I'm looking for the part that tells them not to worry about me personally.

Some searching turned up "言っとくけど" but based on the example sentences　[here](http://ameblo.jp/englishartwork/entry-10369799409.html), I'm not sure it means quite the same thing. Can anyone suggest an expression? Thanks.

Comment: *"Just so you know, the printer is broken"* actually does sound like a request to fix the printer..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you probably can say
"[念]{ねん}のため(に)(or [一応]{いちおう})[伝]{つた}えとくけど、プリンタ[壊]{こわ}れてるよ/[故障]{こしょう}してるよ"
"念のため(に)(or 一応)伝えておきますが、プリンタ壊れてますよ/故障してますよ。"(polite)
"念のため(に)(or 一応)[言]{い}っとくけど、プリンタ故障してるよ。"
"念のため(に)(or 一応)言っておきますけど、プリンタ故障してますよ。(polite)"
or maybe more casually
"(あ、)そうそう、(~~さん、)プリンタ故障してるよ/してますよ。"
"(あ、)そうだ、そう言えば(~~さん、)プリンタ故障してるよ/してますよ。"

Comment: Is this ～とく the contraction of ～ておく again? (Just wanting to make sure)

Comment: @Flaw-san Ah yes, again~~ ^^

Comment: Thanks. These sound like a good way to handle the situation I described.

Comment: @Chocolate-san. Thanks for your verification =)

Comment: @infinitecardinal And as usual, don't forget to "accept" an answer if it answers your question.  Thanks~

Comment: @summea Oops. Still figuring this thing out. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @infinitecardinal No problem!  Welcome to the forum...!

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to Chocolate's answer is the adverb `ちなみに`.

Comment: How about `ただし` as an alternate as well?

Comment: @フレヂィ No. That will not work.